# Check for Updates (ElementaryOS 6.1)

Tags: updates

I can't update software

This is error messsage

```
E: http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt Mirrorlist is not (yet) available (Could not connect to mirrors.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.89.32), connection timed out) 
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal Release' no longer has a Release file. W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal Release is not (yet) available (Downloading mirror file failed) 
E: The repository 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates Release' no longer has a Release file. W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates Release is not (yet) available
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange but seems to happen. Have a look:

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-making-mirror-mirrors-ubuntu-com-highly-available/

Or more directly see if you replace the path with a file from this list matching your country:
http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to see all the PPAs added in your system:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Look for PPA here and then remove the .list file associated with PPA using the following command:

> sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/**PPA_Name_list**

then, add repository

```
sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list
```

update repository

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved using the tip from an [Ubuntu topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110307/603553). It looks like it is related to some environment variables needed to the update operation with the sudo user.

Basically it suggests to use `-E` with sudo to pass on those environment variables to the elevated user:

`sudo -E apt-get update`

I did it once on terminal and AppCenter came back to work.